# changing class of body depending on page

Tags: php, javascript, css

Hello I am having the following trouble. I need to change the body class depending on what page I am now. For example if I am on index page  if I am on cart page  ets. The class name must be a variable that I can pass to body using PHP or JS. I am very week in JS so please give me an example how can I do it? or can I do it at all?

Comment: have you tried anything before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

switch($pageIdentifier) {
    case "index":
        $class = "class-index";
    case "cart":
        $class = "class-cart";
    default:
        $class = "class-index";
}

?>
```

in html:

```
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the break statements after each case... It took me a couple of minutes to figure out why i $class always ended it up being set to default :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP echo a variable for the ID

```
<body id="<?php echo $anId; ?>">
```

Use jQuery to set the body's attribute id

```
$("body").attr("id", "this_is_the_is")
```

Comment: Sorry is it possible to avoid using JS?

Answer (score 1):

It works without using js. if you predefine your classname in a php snippet in front of the body tag.

```
<?php $class="siteclass"; ?>

<body class="<?php echo $siteclass; ?>">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP: `printf('<body class="%s">', $className)`
In jQuery: `$('body').addClass(className)`
In pure JS: `document.getElementsByTagName('body').className = className`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the individual `classes` for each `page` like,
for index.php => index class
for cart.php  => cart class

Here some code which may help you,

**CSS**

```
.cart{
   /* css */
}
.index{
   /* different css */
}
```

And in your page use the script like,

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    //Let your url like http://example.com/index.php
    urlArray=window.location.href.split('/'); // will give array
    cls=urlArray[urlArray.length-1].split('.')[0];// will give index
    document.body.className=cls;// add this class to your body element
</script>
```